# C program:Converting infix to postfix using linked list stack and queue

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, queue, postfix-mta

This is the first time I learn programming. I'm a first year unversity student. My major is software engineering. This is my third assignment for software class.
The teacher wants this program reads in an infix expression from the command line and outputs a postfix expression. We should use "the Shunting Yard algorithm".We should have 2 linked list queue and 1 linked list stack. 2 queues for holding input and output and a stack for holding operators. We also should write general enqueue,dequeue, pop,push function that I already did.

The Shunting Yard algorithm:

1. put arguments into input queue
2. dequeue token from input queue
3. if oprand(number),add to output queue
4. if operator, the pop operators off stack and add to output queue as long as top operator on stack has higher or equal precedence, then push new operator onto stack
5. return to step 1 as long as tokens remain in input
6. pop remaining operators from stack and add to output queue

The program should operate as follows:
programename 34 / 5 + 16 * 2
postfix: 34 5 / 16 2 * +
We also should space between each output

This is so hard for me as a beginner. I already spend more than thirty hour in this program. But the program doesn't work. The program continues run in the "while" loop in main function and never stop. I would be very aprciate if someone can help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
 struct listnode {
    //Define structure of the node
    char *element;
    struct listnode* pnext;
};

struct Stack {
    //Define structure of the stack
    struct listnode* ptop;
};


struct Queue {
    //Define structure of the queue
    struct listnode* pfront;
    struct listnode* prear;
};

void push (struct Stack* stack,char* element);
char* pop (struct Stack* stack);
void enqueue(struct Queue* queue,char* element);
char* dequeue(struct Queue* queue);
void s_travel(struct Stack* stack);
void q_travel(struct Queue* stack);
int precedence(char* x);
int empty(struct Stack* stack);
char* peek(struct Stack* stack);




int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {


    struct Stack stack;
    struct Queue input_queue;
    struct Queue output_queue;
    stack.ptop = NULL;
    input_queue.pfront = NULL;
    input_queue.prear = NULL;
    output_queue.pfront = NULL;
    output_queue.prear = NULL;


    if (argc<3) {
        //If the arguments is less then 3, unavailable input
        printf("Input error");
        return -1;
    }


    int i=0;
    //Put all the arguments into the input_queue
    for (i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        enqueue(&input_queue,argv[i]);
    }

    printf("infix expression is : ");
    q_travel(&input_queue);
    printf("at the beginning, the peek of the stack is %s         \n",peek(&stack));


   for (i=1;i<argc;i++) {  
   //Token from input_queue
    char *token;
    char *x;
    token = dequeue(&input_queue);

    if(atof(token)) {
        //If the element is a number,put it into output_queue
        enqueue(&output_queue,token);
    }

     else {
         /*If the element is a operator, c
     * ompare the precedence of the top element of the stack and the precedence of token element
     */
         char *peek1;
         peek1=peek(&stack);

         while ((precedence(peek1) >= precedence(token)) && (peek1 != NULL)){
             /*while the precedence of the top element of the stack is greater
             and equal to the precedence of token element*/
            printf("inside,the top of the stack is %s \n",peek1);
            //Pop element out of the stack and put it into output_queue
            x = pop(&stack);
            printf("after pop,x is %s,the top of the stack is %s \n",x,peek1);
            enqueue(&output_queue,x);
        }
        //Then, push the new operator(token) into the stack
        push(&stack,token);
        }
}

   while(peek(&stack)!=NULL) {
       //Enqueue remaining operator from stack into output_queue
       char *elem = pop(&stack);
       enqueue(&output_queue,elem);
   }
    printf("Postifx expression is :\n");
    q_travel(&output_queue); 
    return 0;
}

void push (struct Stack* stack,char* element) {
    //Allocate a new node
    struct listnode* new_node = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
    new_node->element = element;
    //Add new node at the top of the stack
    new_node->pnext = stack->ptop;
    stack->ptop = new_node;
}


char* pop (struct Stack* stack_buffer) {
    //If the stack is not empty
    if (stack_buffer->ptop) {
        //Create a temporary node to replace top(removed) node
        struct listnode *pelem = stack_buffer->ptop;
        //The top pointer points to the next node
        stack_buffer->ptop = pelem->pnext;
        //Store the element of the removed node
        char *elem = pelem->element;
        //Remove node from memory
        free(pelem);
        //Return the element of the node that we removed
        return elem;
    }
    //If the stack is empty, removing element fails,return -1
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void enqueue(struct Queue* queue,char *element) {
    //Allocate a new node
    struct listnode *new_node = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
    new_node->element = element;
    new_node->pnext = NULL;
    //If the queue is not empty,add new node at the end of the queue
    if (queue->prear) {
        queue->prear->pnext = new_node;
    }
    //If the queue is empty,add new node at front of the queue
    else {
        queue->pfront = new_node;
    }
    //Added node becomes new rear node
    queue->prear = new_node;

}

char* dequeue(struct Queue* queue) {
    /*Create a temporary node to replace the front node of the queue
    struct listnode *pelem = queue->pfront;*/
    //If the queue is not empty
    if (queue->pfront) {
        //Store the element of the front node
        char *elem = queue->pfront->element;
        //The front pointer points to the next node
        queue->pfront = queue->pfront->pnext;
        //If the queue only has one node
        if(pelem == queue->prear) {
            //After removing the only node, the queue becomes empty
            queue->prear = NULL;
        }
        //Remove node from memory
        free(pelem);
        //Return the element of the node that we removed
        return elem;
    }
    //If the queue is empty, removing node fails,return NULL
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}


void s_travel(struct Stack* buffer) {
    //Function to print out the element in the stack
    //Create a temporary node to replace the top node of the stack
    struct listnode* elem = buffer->ptop;
    while(elem != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", elem->element);
        elem = elem->pnext;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void q_travel(struct Queue* buffer) {
    //Function to print out the element in the queue
    //Create a temporary node to replace the front node of the stack
    struct listnode* elem = buffer->pfront;
    while(elem != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", elem->element);
        elem = elem->pnext;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int precedence(char* operator) {
    /*Function to determine the precedence of the operator,prior operator has greater return value*/
    printf("entering precedence with %s \n",operator);

     if (operator == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
     else if (strcmp(operator,"(")==0){
        printf("Pr: %s 0\n",operator);
        return 0;
    }

    else if (strcmp(operator,"+")==0||strcmp(operator,"-")==0) {
        printf("Pr: %s 1\n",operator);
        return 1;
    }

    else if ( (strcmp(operator,"*")==0) || (strcmp(operator,"/")==0) || (strcmp(operator,"%")==0) || (strcmp(operator,"x")==0) ) {
        printf("Pr: %s 2\n",operator);
        return 2;
    }


    else {
        return -2;
    }
    return -3;
}


int empty(struct Stack* stack) {
    //Function to check if the stack is empty
    //If the stack is empty, the return value would be 1;otherwise, it would be 0
    return NULL == stack->ptop;
}


char* peek(struct Stack* stack) {
    //Function to find out the top element of the stack
    //If the stack is empty, return NULL
    if (empty(stack)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //If the stack is not empty, return the top element of the stack
    char* elem = stack->ptop->element;
    return elem;
}
```

Comment: Don't expect to write a large program and have it either work or not work.  Build it up gradually with parts that you can verify are working as you go.

Comment: In your `while ((precedence(peek1) >= precedence(token)) && (peek1 != NULL))`, neither the variable `peek1`, nor the variable `token` are changing ==> never-ending loop.